# When is $G/N \cong H/K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Suppose the following:

1. $G \cong H$
2. $N \trianglelefteq G$
3. $K \trianglelefteq H$
4. $N \cong K$

What is the requirement that $\alpha: G/N \to H/K$ is an isomorphism?

I found a counterexample like for $G = \mathbb{Z} = H$ and $N = 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $K = 3\mathbb{Z}$, but are there such groups that work?

### EDIT:

I just practiced with Overleaf, and I want to know if it's correct. I made the detailed proof with what you guys helped me in the comments. I'm a beginner doing Overleaf papers, so please let me know if you see any mistakes. Here is the [link](https://www.overleaf.com/project/61cfa2d357ebf3786f547bed).

Comment: Finite cyclic groups?${}{}$

Comment: @markvs, what do you mean in your comment?

Comment: Is the definition of $\alpha$ obvious?

Comment: Is it true for finite cyclic groups?

Comment: The statement is also true for simple groups because $N=K=\{1\}$ or $G/N=H/K=\{1\}$.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo, I think not because I found a counterexample. So, it's not true in general.

Comment: Your Q contains $\alpha$ which is undefined.

Comment: Should the question be, "does there exist an isomorphism $\alpha: G/N\to H/K$?"

Comment: @Shaun, yes! That is correct!

Comment: @markvs, why did you say finite cyclic groups. I'm thinking to prove this, but it's difficult for me.

Comment: I think there's no loss in generality in assuming $G=H$. Then maybe the condition you are looking for is that $N$ and $K$ be conjugate, that is, that there exist $g$ in $G$ such that $g^{-1}Ng=K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ and $ G $ are isomorphic, there exist an isomorphism $\varphi $ between them. Consider the homomorphism $ \pi:G\to H/_{K} $ defined by $$ \pi\left(g\right)=\varphi\left(g\right)K $$

Now,a sufficient condition for what you desire would be that $ \text{ker}\left(\pi\right)\subseteq N $. Because then we can define $ \psi:G/_{N}\to H/_{K}$ by: $$ \psi\left(gN\right)=\pi\left(g\right) $$This homomorphism is obviously surjective, and if $ \psi\left(g_{1}N\right)=\psi\left(g_{2}N\right) $, then $ \pi\left(g_{1}^{-1}g_{2}\right)\in K $ so that $ g_{1}^{-1}g_{2}\in\ker\pi\subseteq N $.

Now, this implies that $ g_{1}N=g_{2}N $ so that $\psi $ is injective and surjective and thus isomorphism

Comment: I think you need to require to have $Ker(\pi)=N$, otherwise you'll only have $G/Ker(\pi) \cong H/K$, right?

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz I wrote an explicit proof. Can you tell where exactly in my proof this assumption is needed?

Comment: You said that it requires to have $\text{ker}(\pi) \subseteq N$ and I said that they should be equal. But now I see it. I saw how proved it. Thank you! My doubt is clear. However, now I know that **IF**  $\text{ker}(\pi) \subseteq N$, then we have the desired isomorphism. How about the converse? If we have the desired isomorphism above, does that mean that $\text{ker}(\pi) \subseteq N$?

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz If we have the desired isomorphism we even have equality since the kernel of an injective homomorphism is the neutral element (which is $N$ )

Comment: So you're saying that $\text{ker}(\pi) \subseteq N \iff G/N \cong H/K$, regardless if $\pi$ is an injective homomorphism or not (where $\text{ker}(\pi) = N$ if $\text{ker}(\pi)$ is injective)?

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz Yes.

Comment: @FreeZe I am having this doubt. Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4=H$ and $N\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2\simeq K$. Note that $N\trianglelefteq G, K\triangleleft H$ such that $G/N\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2, H/K\simeq \mathbb{Z}_4$. If we have $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ as identity isomorphism, and $\pi:G\rightarrow H/K$ defined by $\pi(g)=gK$, we are getting $ker(\pi)=N=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Yet the contradiction is above. Where did it go wrong ?

Comment: @KON3, how do you prove that $G/N \cong H/K$?

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz That is my query. There is no isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ but yet all the conditions were satisfied. So what to modify further that was my curiosity.

Comment: This is certainly possible to find $N, K$ such that $G/N\simeq \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $H/K\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, satusfying all the condition stated in OPs post, for which one such example is shown above. But then the problem begins for conclusion.

Comment: @KON3 is your $\pi$ definition injective?

Comment: Will that be required? Because i followed the discussion "that $ker(\pi)\subseteq N\iff G/N\simeq H/K$, regardless if $\pi$ is an injective homomorphism or not (where $ker(\pi)=N$ if $ker(\pi)$ is injective)"

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz I think my $\pi$ definition is not injective. Will it be the reason that such conflict in the example arrived ?

Comment: @KON3 It went wrong here: in your example $ N=\left\{ 0\right\} \times\left\{ 0,2\right\}  $ and $ K=\left\{ 0,1\right\} \times\left\{ 0\right\} $. So that $(1,0)$ is in the kernel but not in $N$.

Comment: BTW the $\psi$ homomorphism does not have to be surjective. Consider $G=\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb{Z}$, $H=N=G$ and $K=\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}$. All conditions are satisfied, but $G/N$ is trivial while $H/K\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ and thus no surjective map $G/N\to H/K$ exists.

Comment: @freakish, you wrote $K$ wrong. You need to write it as $K = \{0\} \oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$. Otherwise, $K$ would not be a subgroup of $G$ because it would take fewer elements than $G$.